# Show only enrolled course in moodle when use logged

Tags: moodle

I have tried front page setting to show only enrolled course .but even this shows not enrolled course.show only enrolled course in moodle when user is logged in moodle site.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set from the theme that when the users sign in, they are redirected to yoursite.com/moodlesitename/my/